# no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value with spring boot client

Tags: spring-boot, rest, httpclient

I am using spring boot application with frontend (spring boot application using thymeleaf) and backend (spring boot REST application )  are separated using REST api. The frontend uses HttpClient to send request to backend. Whenever I try to update an object the HttpClient creates an error for json parsing. The request is not accepted by the backend (ProcessDTORequest object ) with error as follows.

The exception is as follows:

```
{"message":"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.app.dataaccess.entity.Process` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('68d22e4d-7116-4130-aa06-9ba120aadc66'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.app.dataaccess.entity.Process` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('68d22e4d-7116-4130-aa06-9ba120aadc66')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 10310] (through reference chain: com.app.ui.dto.request.ProcessDTORequest[\"answeredQuestionnaires\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.app.dataaccess.entity.AnsweredQuestionnaire[\"process\"])","httpStatus":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","timeStamp":"2022-11-04T08:44:35.9108286Z"}
```

HttpClient method for  post request is as follows:

```
    public  String executePost(
            final String url, final Object payLoad, final Map<String, String> headers,
            final Map<String, String> params) throws Exception {
        final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();


        // Add query strings to URL
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url);

        for (final Map.Entry<String, String> elm : params.entrySet()) {
            builder = builder.setParameter(elm.getKey(), elm.getValue());
        }

        // can change for HttpPut, HttpPost, HttpPatch
        final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(builder.build());

        // Add headers from input map
        for (final Map.Entry<String, String> elm : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.addHeader(elm.getKey(), elm.getValue());
        }

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // Send Json String as body, can also send UrlEncodedFormEntity
        final StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payLoad));
        request.setEntity(entity);

        try  {
            final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            System.out.println("Return response status code: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("Return response status code: "+response.getStatusLine());
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // Read response string using EntityUtils class of Apache http client library
                // Serialize json string into map or any other object
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } else {
                throw new Exception(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
//                throw new Exception(String.format("Response status code was  and response was ",
//                        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())));
            }
        } catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
            throw new Exception("Client protocol Exception occurred while executing request", e);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

I used the configuration for object mapper as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper; }
}
```

**Process.java** (this is used for serializing/deserializing)

```
    @Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)
public class Process  {

    private UUID processId;

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<UnitType> units = new ArrayList<>();

    private String furtherComment;

    private List<AnsweredQuestionnaire> answeredQuestionnaires = new ArrayList<>()


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Process)) return false;
        Process process = (Process) o;
        return getProcessId().equals(process.getProcessId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getProcessId());
    }
}
```

**The json from the server is like the following**

```
   {
  "@id": "bba35e58-5d4b-44ce-9a5a-486f55f79af7",
  "processId": "21ef7f9d-4fcc-417c-96e8-4327206d2592",
  "users": [
    {
      "@id": "69d2f392-8213-4f34-9cb5-f0c403170787",
      "userId": "5a17ec5f-c20a-4873-93af-bf69fad4eb26",
      "roles": [
        {
          "roleId": "f6ad33a7-9d03-4260-81c2-a4a4c791e30a",
          "users": []
        }
      ],
      "processes": []
    }
  ],
  "units": [
    {
      "unitTypeId": "c784d197-1dc7-446e-b3e5-6468a7954878",
      "unit": {
        "unitId": "aba76d05-e2ea-4b5a-828b-349966595258"
      },
      "isResponsibleUnit": true
    }
  ],
  "furtherComment": "",
  "answeredQuestionnaires": [
    {
      "@id": "7ca1af09-eefd-4c56-9587-581858fbbc57"
    }
  ]
}
```

The relation between the entities Process, AnsweredQuestionnaire and User is as follows:
Between Process and AnsweredQuestionnaire (One-to-many) respectively.
Between Process and User (many-to-many).
Between Process and UnitType (one-to-many) respectively.

**AnsweredQuestionnaire.java**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnsweredQuestionnaire {

    private UUID answeredQuestionnaireId;


    private Questionnaire questionnaire;

    private Process process;

    public void addProcessToAnsweredQuestionnaire(Process process){
        //remove old association
        if(this.process != null){
            this.process.getAnsweredQuestionnaires().remove(this);
        }
        this.process = process;

        //add new association
        if(process != null){
            this.process.getAnsweredQuestionnaires().add(this);
        }
    } 
}
```

**User.java**

```
    @Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private UUID userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addProcessToUser(Process process){
        this.processes.add(process);
        process.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProcessFromUser(Process process){
        this.processes.remove(process);
        process.getUsers().remove(this);
    }

}
```

**ProcessDTORequest.java** (this class is on the backend accepting the request from the frontend)

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProcessDTORequest {

    private UUID processId;

    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<AnsweredQuestionnaire> answeredQuestionnaires = new HashSet<>();

    private Set<UnitType> units = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**UnitType.java**

```
    @Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UnitType {
    private UUID unitTypeId;

    private Unit unit;

    private Boolean isResponsibleUnit = false;
}
```

Comment: Why do I get @id in json

Comment: Please let me know if something not clear

Comment: Could you please append the classes of all child objects (User, UnitType, AnsweredQuestionnaire etc.) as well?

Comment: is it better to use custom serializer/ deserializer ? If yes should I have to do for all cases?

Comment: I have added a demo application to simulate the situation here https://github.com/Er-Iftekhar/frontend-app-using-java. Any suggestion to make the serialization and deserialization work will help